# Cannot install the xlwings ribbon in Excel 2007

Tags: xlwings

I've installed xlwings and its addin, but cannot get the ribbon to appear in Excel 2007.

The xlwings.xlam file is in the default User Startup folder and I've checked that it is included in the Trusted Locations.

I can browse to that file using the Add-In dialogue, add it to the 'Add-Ins available' list and tick it but still no ribbon.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have same issue. Please post if you find an answer.

Comment: @Owen did you end up finding a solution? I have the same issue...